# Apache2 VirtualDocumentRoot and Proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, reverse-proxy

I use a very simple `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default` configuration like

```
<VirtualHost 117.121.241.184>
UseCanonicalName    Off
VirtualDocumentRoot /srv/www/%0
Options All ExecCGI
LogFormat "%V %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\"" vhost_common
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log vhost_common
</VirtualHost>
```

Where 117.121.241.184 is the IP of my machine I'm setting upon.

Now I want to do something a little complicated, i.e. proxy a NodeJS instance like so:

```
<VirtualHost foobar.example.com:80>
 <Location />
   ProxyPass http://localhost:3000/
   ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000/
 </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

And it doesn't work. Apache just serves `/srv/www/foobar.example.com`. If I put the "VirtualHost foobar.example.com" stanza **above** the **VirtualDocumentRoot** one, then everything gets redirected to the proxy, which I don't want.

I just want the particular domain "foobar.example.com" handled by the proxy, and everything else, the VirtualDocumentRoot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking to configure is name-based virtual hosting, where the virtual host is selected based on the `Host` header sent in the HTTP request by the client.

To do this, you'll need a `NameVirtualHost` directive, and for your `<VirtualHost>` blocks to match exactly to what you've configured in it.  For instance:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName default
  VirtualDocumentRoot /srv/www/%0
  # other needed config directives here
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName foobar.example.com
  <Location />
    ProxyPass http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000/
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I wonder if this is related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58957049/virtualdocumentroot-and-proxypass-mapping-url-for-each-subdomain